# Which PCB stackup is better for noise immunity and why?

Tags: pcb, stack-up

Is a two layer board with a Signal plane and Ground plane better?

Or is a four layer board with Signal, +Voltage, -Voltage, and Ground better? Why?

Comment: A 4 layer stack up with the signal next to ground would be best.  I don't think putting ground opposite -V makes sense.  Do you actually need to do that?

Comment: @user1850479 well if you have ground next to a power plane it forms a big capacitor. The four layer stackup is how a co-worker designed a board and I want to change to the two layer configuration. There are only two ICs total on this board so without the power planes its still very easy to route the power.

Comment: This is a few lines that asks for mountains of effort in reply. The site is not for free personal tutoring. Please edit your question and detail your situation and what you already know, show all that you have discovered for yourself on the subject.

Comment: Putting your ground next to negative does give the negative plane some distributed capacitance, but now it means your signal layer is referenced to the positive rail. That can be ok, but it means that power supply noise is coupled into the signal layer and that the return path for signal currents is more complex.

Comment: **It depends on your design. And cost budget. Maybe a 1 layer board is good enough like DVD players.**

Comment: signal+ground 2 layer board can be much better than the awkward 4-layer stackup that you mention. But this really depends on a lot of other factors: e.g. which ICs, which voltage rails for which ICs, power consumption, frequency range etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is a four layer board with Signal, +Voltage, -Voltage, and Ground
> better? Why?

A two layer PCB has a ~50 mil core with two outer layers. A four layer PCB has ~30 mil core with 7 mil prepreg separating the outer layers.

In general, I would say that a four layer board is better. Why? because the inner layers are closer to the signal layers (outer layers), providing more capacitance which will yield a slightly better design.

Four layer boards are also easier to lay out, and you can separate signals and provide bigger power planes and shorter routing for signals (in general) because there are more layers to work with. A shorter trace or bigger power plane gives you less resistance and inductance. You can also shield inner conductors with a 4 layer design.